# Android testing - testing multiple APKs

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, apk

I would like to run Unit test/ E2E test on application which is consists of multiple APKs.
Can you please advise if there is a way to do that?

Comment: So currently, my idea is to create test application (apk) for sending messages to other apks and register it to receive real apks outputs.